# Conditional filters for views

Tags: views

I have 4 filters for my nodes. These filters work with taxonomy terms.
So I have 4 taxony lists:

- Type (a,b,c)
- length (d,e,f,g,h,i,j)

If I select Type (a) then length should only give me the possibilities that actually are possible with the length for example f,g,h. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
What you are asking for is typical [faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) functionality.
You should be looking in the direction of [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi).

Cheers!